# How can you animate a view back and forth between two states on Android, while supporting backpressure?

Tags: android, android-animation

Let's say you have a **BLUE** `FrameLayout` and a `Button` called `TOGGLE COLOR`. Pressing `TOGGLE COLOR` will do one of two things:

1. When the `FrameLayout` is **BLUE**: change its `backgroundColor` from **BLUE** -> **BLACK**.
2. When the `FrameLayout` is **BLACK**: change its `backgroundColor` from **BLACK** -> **BLUE**.

This is pretty easy. Now let's say that you want this color change animation to happen over 2 seconds.

Problem: the user can then press the `TOGGLE COLOR` button 40 times over those two seconds. Queuing up 40 animations on the main thread is bad, and all sorts of frames will be dropped. What's the best way to address this, using say the `ViewProperAnimator` API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a flag (`boolean`) that is set when the user presses the `TOGGLE COLOR` button and unset after the two second animation. If the user presses the button while the flag is set, then make it so that nothing will happen. A simple `if-else` conditional can handle this.

Another way you could do this, so that the user doesn't think your UI is unresponsive, is to add a color value repeatedly over the two seconds to the background color to go from blue to black or vice-versa. If the user presses the button then multiply the color value by -1 (so then you'll be subtracting the color value).

I'm unfamiliar with the `ViewProperAnimator` API, but I don't think it has the capability to limit the effect of a user pressing a button 40 times within a 2 second window.

Comment: yeah I was hoping there would be a built-in way to track state as I don't want to pollute my fragment too much, but I cannot seem to find one.